# Obtain excel activeworkbook activesheet activecell value and put into a c# winform textbox

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm trying to get a string value that may be in any excel 2010 workbook in the activecell and use that value in a c# applications winform textbox. I'm using vs2015 and excel 2010.

Here's what I've tried with no success.

```
//Get active excel instance

Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

//Get active excel workbook

Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = (Excel.Workbook)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;

//Get active excel worksheet

Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;            

//Get value for excel

string AValue = xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2].ToString();

//Put value in c# winform textbox

txtSearchPattern.Text = AValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

*using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel*

Members of a `Range.Cells` collection are Range objects, not strings.  Try `Cells[x,y].Value2` to retrieve the cell's value.

Also, the currently selected Range object is an application-wide variable `Application.Selection`, so you should be able retrieve the value of the top-left most cell in the active selection using `Application.Selection.Cells[1,1].Value2` without referencing any workbook/worksheets.

Edit: In this instance, you're probably better off using `Application.Activecell` because Selection can return non-range objects (pictures, etc).

Comment: I tried the .Value2 but vs2015 doesn't accept that. I also tried                                                                                                         string AValue = Application.Selection.Cells[1, 1].Value2;  but vs2015 doesn't recognize selection.                                                                                                                                                                                                                          I'm trying to add the excel activecell value to a textbox inside of a c# winform application running in vs2015.

Comment: Hrmm... I do all my development in the VBA IDE these days, but assuming you're using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel you should see both an [activecell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.activecell.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) (which I now realize is better than selection here, updated my answer) and [selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.selection.aspx) properties of the Application object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but it seemed to allow the program to run and catch the null exception error.

```
            try
            {           
            //Get active excel instance
            Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

            //Get active excel workbook
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = (Excel.Workbook)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;

            //Get active excel worksheet
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;

            //Get value for excel          
            string AValue = xlApp.ActiveCell.Value2.ToString();

            //Return value to winform textbox
            txtSearchPattern.Text = AValue;    
            }

            catch(NullReferenceException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ActiveCell was null");
            }
```

Comment: This stopped working again. Now I can't seem to get the activeworkbook. I'm not clear on this type of programming, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the following code to a WinForm having a button (**button1**) with click event handler (**button1_Click**) as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Excel.Interop;

namespace XYZ
{
    public partial class ABC : Form
    {
    Excel.Range activecell = null;
    Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

    public ABC()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (xlApp.Selection is Excel.Range)
        {
            activecell = xlApp.Selection as Excel.Range;

            //Return value to winform textbox
            txtSearchPattern.Text = activecell.Value2.ToString();
        }
    }
}
}
```

When you click on a cell in an Excel worksheet which contains a value and subsequently click on **button1**, the textbox (**txtSearchPattern**) has its value updated correspondingly.